# Parse/Display XML from a POST Method

Tags: ios, xml, parsing, button

Ok,so on my iOS app I have a `HTTP Post` method that returns `xml`, like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<geocode>
    <suburb>Sydney</suburb>
    <state>NSW</state>
</geocode>
```

It returns through a `HTTP POST` method that gets the Latitude and Longtitude

What I what to do is display this `XML` on a button or on a label.
But not the code just like **Bold** Sydney and less for NSW.
I have the code saved as

```
NSData *urlData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
NSString *strdata=[[NSString alloc]initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

So I usually call on the `strdata` to get the `XML` but it displays it in its code form and thats the problem. I looked at using NSXMLParser but I couldnt figure out how to use it.

Comment: What are you trying to do ? What happened when you use NSXMLParser ?

Comment: I couldnt figure out where to put it for one and I didnt know whether it needed another framework or what it needed.

Comment: see this example http://iosbala.blogspot.in/2013/04/how-to-using-nsxmlparser-in-iphone-sdk.html

Answer (score 0):

Declare a property like:

```
@porperty (nonatomic, strong) NSXMLParser  *parser;
```

And Implement a method like:

```
- (void)parseXML
{
   NSData *urlData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
   _parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:urlData];
   [_parser setDelegate:self];
   [_parser parse];
}
```

And implement the following `NSXMLParser` Delegate methods:

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
```

Check the following links:

1. [RSS Reader](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-rss-reader-tutorial/)
2. [NSXMLParser Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: Where am I meant to place the Delegate methods, In the `AppDelegate.m/.h` files?

Comment: @user3089637: No in the same file where you are adding the parser. Please check the tutorial for more info.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/r6UIJIj.png I did the tutorial but I'm only supposed to have one result spanning of state and suburb and then display that result formatted/parsed on a label/button. I also have an error that is that photo.

Comment: @user3089637: did you check my answer I used _parser not parser also not use `@synthesize parser;`

Comment: Synthesizing it asked to change all the `_parser` to `parser`. So all good.

Comment: Wait so how do I display the parsed XML?